# Error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1241

I am trying this QUERY, and return this weird error. What does it mean?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM newRowP a WHERE a.rowId IN 
(SELECT * FROM newCellP b WHERE b.cellId IN 
(SELECT * FROM newproviderP c WHERE c.pId IN ('3000344','245')))
```

Comment: What is the 'weird error'...?

Comment: @TheWolf: I'd hazard a guess at "*Error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)*".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your subqueries, which `SELECT *`, are returning more than one column; whereas `IN ()` requires exactly one column to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

There should only be one column returned from the result of a `SELECT` statement in a subquery. eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM newRowP a 
WHERE a.rowId IN (SELECT colName FROM newCellP b .....)
```

but a better way of using `IN` is `JOIN`ing the tables.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    newRowP a
        INNER JOIN newCellP b
            ON a.rowID = b.colName
        INNER JOIN newProviderP c
            ON b.cellID = c. colName
WHERE   c.pid IN ('3000344','245')
```

where `colname` are the columns that you want to link with other table.